# Have there been any geospatial applications run in OpenStack by non-governmental entities?

Tags: open-source-gis, cloud-gis

This [whitepaper about NASA's Nebula project](http://nebula.nasa.gov/media/uploads/nasa-nebula-in-action.pdf), describes how cloud computing was used by NASA's [Short-term Prediction Research and Transition Center](http://weather.msfc.nasa.gov/sport/) to identify damage scars left by tornadoes.

Since then, [Nebula was open-sourced to create OpenStack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStack#History).

Have there been any geospatial applications run in [OpenStack](http://www.openstack.org/) by non-governmental entities?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you look on the home page at http://www.openstack.org/ there appears to be a "Latest" section, and that looks to list projects using the technology, among other news related to it, I would suggest you read through that and other news pages on the site, you'll most likley find the info you need there.

### UPDATE

Excerpt from the main web page's latest section...

Announcing eDeploy Fri, Jun 21st 2013

**Kwapi: an energy efficiency architecture Thu, Jun 20th 2013**

Roadmap for Heat Havana (part 1)It's been quite a… Thu, Jun 20th 2013
[Live Demo 06-26-2013] Build Your Private Cloud with Open Source Software: SUSE Cloud powered by OpenStack Thu, Jun 20th 2013
An history of OpenStack open source project governance Thu, Jun 20th 2013

The second option (Kwapi) appears to be a project using OpenStack

As I previously mentioned however, if you browse through the various pages of the site there are many pages that list amongst other things, Projects that use the technology.